# after formatting NSDate, new date is one day earlier than real date

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a strange problem. After transforming my stringDate to a NSDate, my NSDate object has one day less than the real date

-example- StringDate = 30 june 2012  --->  NSDate is 29 june 2012

Here is my code.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[genkInfo objectForKey:CALENDAR_DATE]];
```

I am transforming this date because I get it back as a string from the webservice. The webservice gives the following back

```
"date": "30/06/2012"
```

Anybody has an idea how this is possible?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

OK so the solution for the question above was to set the TimeZone

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];
```

But now I have another question. Now the format is YYYY-MM-DD but I want YYYY-DD-MM

How can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Could there be a time zone issue where information about time and time zone is being ignored when creating the date which makes it be 00:00:00 +000? That date being printed me be printed as if it was your time zone which could be another day.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following :

> [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT+0:00"]];

Actually the timezone the data is in.

Comment: This fixed my first problem! But I have edited my question with another question

Comment: This is a correct answer to your original question, you should mark it as accepted and post your other question as a new question.